# What is ecotraining in CSGO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Few days back, I had downloaded some **extremely difficult, high-reflex bot profiles** to have more fun. (because expert bots were losing to me)

There was an **ecotraining.cfg** configuration file, which I pasted in the directory and executed it from the console.

I found out that after executing it, ***the CTs had*** ***3 bots with rifles*** and my T side had *me as the lone player* with **only a P250** equipped. (**No buy menu**, only you can **acquire M4s** dropped on the ground)

I wanted to know about this thing, it makes me more frustrating.

***UPDATED:***

Link for the **ecotraining.cfg** : [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u4l3mdos55x6aff/bots.rar)

Comment: *Exact* same [question/response](https://www.questarter.com/q/what-is-ecotraining-in-csgo-15_325867.html) on a different site with same usernames.

Comment: @Childishforlife There have been known issues with other sites scraping stackexchange for content :(

Comment: @Chidishforlife Is there any way I can lodge a complaint? He is using my name and content without my consent.

Answer (score 9):

Given your explanation of the cfg, it would appear that it's designed to simulate an Eco round.

That is when you have lost a series of rounds (or lost the first ever round), the last one of which was a gun round, you don't have enough money for a full buy but your enemy does.

In such cases "Eco" is called where you save your money during that round and only get cheep but good pistol and maybe one nade.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about that. I think it was designed to give training about how to save your money, but just after executing it thing above happens. And also, it doesn't allow me to buy. Even if I have the highest score or K/D ratio, it doesn't make me win.

Comment: @AadhavVignesh As I told you it's designed to simulate an Eco round. In that case you're not supposed to buy and spend money, K/D doesn't matter. You could be carrying your entire team and yet still end up in situation where you need to save for a round.

Comment: I don't think it is used for simulating an Eco round, it acts weirdly after executing, and I don't know how to describe it.

Comment: Link for the **ecotraining.cfg** : [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u4l3mdos55x6aff/bots.rar)

Comment: @AadhavVignesh Do the cfg files display as text?  Either way, I think you should explain what else is acting "weirdly" and what that means.  All the description you gave implies that is _is_ to simulate an eco round.  It's trying to simulate when you can't buy and your enemies can.  Being able to win those rounds can completely turn matches around, so there is a logical reason to train for it.

Comment: @Иво Недев Your answer is right but Childishforlife gave me the right link, which already solved much of my issue. I do have a question, which I'll post now, hope you might answer it correctly!

Answer (score 3):

I found the reddit post of the user who created a version of this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/1mmg72/incomplete_realistic_bot_difficulties/).

As mentioned above, this is mostly used for practicing your pistols vs rifles when you are half buying/full eco.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for that. Even though I killed the CTs five times without dying as stated by him, but still I don't win the round. Maybe due to his incomplete work? If you solve this problem for me, I'll definitely upvote and accept this answer! (Try contacting Wally3k if you have a Reddit account.)